# When do we say "I cycle to work", "I bike to work" and "I ride a bike to work"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

These are my study:

It seems like the verb "**cycle**" refers to "**go by bicycle**" is often used in British English more.

And the verb "**bike**" can be used for both "**bicycle**" and "**motorbike**"

"**a bike**" can refer to a bicycle or [informally refer to a motorcycle](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bike)

But I don't know when we say "**I cycle to work**", "**I bike to work**" and "**I ride a bike to work**".

Comment: We only say ***I cycle to work*** if we're doing so on a "push-bike". We can say ***I bike to work*** with either a push-bike *or* a scooter / motorbike. But you knew that anyway. And we don't usually say ***I ride a bike to work*** - but when we do, the extra words ***ride a*** don't change the meaning. I can't see what the question is here.

Comment: Oh - are you perhaps asking whether to ***ride*** more strongly implies *powered* transport? If so, the fact that [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ride+a+motorbike%2Cride+a+cycle&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) comparing ***ride** a motorbike* and *ride a cycle* looks much the same as [***own...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=own+a+motorbike%2Cown+a+cycle&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) should be enough to show that overall there's no significant implication of that with ***ride***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm a veteran cyclist and I've never heard "push-bike" before. 30 seconds of DuckDuckGo says it just means "bicycle", but you seem to be using it in contrast to "bicycle". What do you mean by the term?

Comment: @gotube I don't know how reputable a source this is, but Wiktionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pushbike says that it's an informal UK word for specifically a *non* -motorized bicycle

Comment: @FumbleFingers By *scooter* which you're contrasting with *push-bike*, I'm guessing you mean those e-scooters?

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: I just mean there's pushbikes and "powered" two-wheeled conveyances. Battery e-scooters and Vespa mopeds / scooters both fall into the latter category. And I only said "push-bike" because there's no confusion about whether that's powered or not - I don't recall *ever* hearing that in an American accent, but even non-native Anglophone *learners* should be able to infer my intended meaning from the context here without me bothering to wrap it up in a link to a definition.

Comment: ...anyway, the OP hasn't responded, so we still don't know if my second comment is relevant or not.

Comment: As a US English speaker, I am completely unfamiliar with the term "push-bike".  I don't think it would also necessarily be understood from context - after all, you propel a bicycle by pedaling it, not pushing it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just because push-bike is very natural to you don't assume anybody gets the meaning from context. I didn't when I first heard the term 30 years or so ago and even today I still have to do a small bit of mental juggling every time I encounter the term. It is a very British-only usage and doesn't make much sense to people that are used to think of bicycles as being "pedaled" in stead of "pushed". Moped is another one that most non-British people have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @stangdon when you first get on a bike, don't you place a foot on the ground and  push yourself before resting it back on its pedal. Push the wheels forward with one foot on the ground and once they're spinning, off you go. No? How else do gain momentum and balance?

Comment: @Tonny: So just do the mental juggling! It was only a ***comment***, and I did put the first use in "scare quotes" to acknowledge that not everyone would recognize the term. But even for those learners who  *didn't* come across it 30 years ago, and therefore can't resolve it through memory, it's either screamingly obvious OR they can just google it. (We are all *online* here, after all! :)

Comment: @Tom: Despite the fact that there are several upvoted answers here, I will vote to close if you don't edit the question text to address my first two comments above. I'm not even going to bother reading those answers or voting on them unless and until it's clear what the question is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, CHatGPT says "**cycle**" is often used for riding a bike as an exercise, but the dictionary says "**cycle means to ride a bicycle**". There is nothing special about my question, I just want to know how native speakers use these phrases in which situation?

Comment: Okay, well since that's the best you can do, I've closevoted for "needs details or clarity".

Comment: US English speaker--I've never encountered "push-bike" but given the nature of the question it was instantly clear to me that it was referring to human-powered vehicles as opposed to the other things that might be called bikes.

Comment: As an Australian English speaker, my wife and I both agree that "push-bike" is one that you "push" on the pedals (ie. manually powered), as opposed to a motorised bike. However "bicycle" would be a synonym. If you use the word "bike" it isn't as clear whether or not it is motorised.

Comment: When writing for an international audience "pedal bike" is probably more useful than "push-bike"; UK legislation often uses "pedal cycle"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

"Cycle to work" seems the most likely.  "Bike to work" could mean bicycle or motorbike.  "Ride a bicycle to work" is exactly the same meaning as "cycle to work, only slightly longer".

There is a government grant scheme called [Cycle to Work](https://www.sustrans.org.uk/our-blog/get-active/2019/everyday-walking-and-cycling/the-cycle-to-work-scheme-explained/?gclid=CjwKCAjwtuOlBhBREiwA7agf1iVUmfqZIuzHvtX1j5cnZHI4fuZnaUi1iZ6RCwsaFeBqjLCTNTlWDxoCTbcQAvD_BwE)

But all three sentences are correct and could be used by a cyclist to describe how they get to work.

Comment: "I bike to work" sounds stilted to me.

Comment: @MikeB I *think* that i other places "bike" is more commonly used as a verb than here in the UK.

Answer (score 10):

[american-english](/questions/tagged/american-english)

I suspect there are differences depending on what side of the Atlantic you're on, but for me, a veteran cyclist from Canada, all three of your sentences are correct and natural to describe commuting by bicycle.

"Cycle" and "ride a bike" only refer to bicycles. I was unsure about "bike" as a verb, so I asked my friends who ride both motorcycles and bicycles, and they say only use "bike" as a verb to mean ride a bicycle, never a motorcycle.

Comment: South of the CA border, the convention is the same, except in TX, where it's "Ah rode ma Harley."

Comment: I once had a long and confusing conversation with someone in a class I was teaching.  We both rode to campus on our bikes.  I rode 10 miles, and it took me about 40 minutes.  He rode 40 miles, and it took him about 30 minutes.  Turns out that my bike was a pedal-powered bicycle, and his was a motorcycle.  So yes, "to cycle" really only refers to a bicycle, but "to bike" could easily refer to a bicycle or motorcycle.  This was in Reno, NV, for the record---the particular regional English is, essentially "Northern California English".

Comment: I wouldn't *say* "cycle" - it sounds very British but the meaning is immediately clear.

Comment: Interestingly, the noun does have a difference - a Biker is on a motorbike, and a Cyclist is on a pedal-cycle.  There's a halfway-house with Mountain-Biker which is a Cyclist on a MTB.   Gotta love English for consistency.

Answer (score 7):

There may well be differences between American and British English, or between sub-regions in either.

Where I live -- Michigan, USA -- we would typically say, "I ride a bicycle to work." If you said "I cycle to work", people would know what you meant, but it's not something we say here.

"Bike" can refer to a bicycle or a motorcycle, but, at least among people I talk to, it more commonly means bicycle. If you said, "I bike to work", I'd understand you to mean that you ride a bicycle.

But it could mean "motorcycle" in the right context. Like if we were talking about motorcycles, I'd assume you meant a motorcycle. Like if you said, "My bike is a Harley", I'd take you to mean motorcycle because I've never heard of a Harley bicycle. (Is there such a thing? I suppose it's possible.)

Comment: Also, a "biker" *usually* refers to a motorcyclist. If we're talking about someone who rides a bicycle, we would usually say "bicyclist". But as you said, "bike" most often refers to a bicycle unless other context implies motorcycle.

Comment: As an American, I agree with your statements. I'd also say that if someone said "I *drive* a bike to work", I would take that to mean a motorcycle, but it's less common to hear compared to "riding a bike".

Comment: @GalacticCowboy "bicyclist" would be shortened to "cyclist" - I've never heard the former outside of formal written English.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Good point. Yes, "biker" is someone who rides a motorcycle. Someone who rides a bicycle is usually a "cyclist". Amusing inconsistancy.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been muddied because it brings in regional usages. Let's set those aside, since it's pretty simple: *cycle* as verb and *bike* as verb are British and American respectively.

But let's focus on the question: Do people say "I [verb] to work," or "I [verb an object] to work." The short answer is: it doesn't much matter. Both are reasonable.

The longer answer: We've got an unusual situation with bicycles here. There's no similar verb form for riding a horse, say; you can't "horse to work." And on the other hand there are other things you could "ride," like scooters or skateboards, so "I ride to work" is vague.

"I ride a bike to work" is not awkward or non-idiomatic. It might be that people would be more likely, though, to say "I ride *my* bike to work." But this construction is no more or less common than "I bike to work," and there's no significant contextual reason to choose one or the other.

Comment: Interesting point about how "*horse* to work" is not something you'd hear, even if someone really did ride a horse to work. However, "*skate* to work" is something you might hear while "*scoot* to work" is not (at least not in the context of riding a scooter).

Comment: "ride" applies to anything with a Saddle, so horses, motorbikes, pedal bikes and anything that you stand on, like scooters and skateboards.   Opposite is anything with a Seat.   The only exception is standing room on a bus, which may or may not be Riding the bus.

Comment: @jordanbtucker I mostly agree, but I do know people who use the verb "to scoot" meaning "to ride a scooter". I would understand the meaning of "scoot to work", although I think it would sound funny.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not sure "ride" has a distinction based on seats or saddles; one might "ride" a ski lift (a seat), as well as a train or roller coaster. I think it's just about being transported.

Comment: @AndyBonner The distinction is a Seat bears all your weight.  A Saddle does not (horse saddle has stirrups, bikes put weight on pedals, motorbike puts weight on pegs)    Other usages like bus, chairlift are more recent.